# Cross-domain JavaScript iFrame-parent access blocked

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I'm designing some "add-on" to certain websites, which should be embedded in them as an iframe. Inside this iframe there is a clickable button aimed at changing the iframe's **position** within the parent website.

Since things are done in coordination with the parent website, I am able to add some code there as well. However it seems I am **not** able to do neither of the following (one of them should suffice):

1. From the iframe, access data within the *parent.document*, in order to move the iframe to the desired position.
2. From the parent website, access data within the iframe, in order to check when the button is clicked.

Both typically produce an error: "Blocked a frame with origin XXX from accessing a frame with origin YYY. Protocols, domains, and ports must match".

Any advice (preferably with code sample) is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing lots of searching around, I came across this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585663/Communication-with-Cross-Domain-IFrame-A-Cross-Bro

I actually tested the method (using my own short piece of code) and it seemed to work on Chrome, Firefox and IE. Now I'm gonna try the "real" implementation...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand based on the information you've provided in your question, cross domain scripting is not possible. What you would need to do is provide a script that the parent-level website can paste into their template/html and run from their domain, similar to how Google does with their analytics system.

As an alternative, try turning your iframe content instead, into a div loaded with the response from a service call made from the parent domain to the iframe domain. You would most likely need to create an API that a requesting site can use. Simply call that URI with whatever parameters you would use when referencing the page you wanted to load in the iframe, and have the script that you run on the parent website handle all the DOM alterations you want to achieve.